# What does "--enable-shared" mean during Ruby compilation?

Tags: ruby, configure

RVM uses this flag for `./configure`. It means "build a shared library for Ruby", but where can I get more information about actually happens when you use this compilation flag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will create `libruby.so` so other programs can use it, e.g. Vim with Ruby support.

Comment: Thanks so much. Did you find out about this through some Ruby docs? Or is it just common knowledge for compiling sources?

Comment: Well, as the help text available from `./configure --help` says it will "build a shared library for Ruby". I just happened to know that it is called `libruby.so`, but pretty much all libraries stick to this convention. The part that it can be used by other programs is just general knowledge about shared libraries. The fact that Vim needs it to work with Ruby properly is just personal experience ;-)

Comment: Is that possible to use for example both of --enable-shared and --enable-ffmpeg flags, to have SO library and Binary output?